# How to properly use GCP's Artifact Repository with Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip

## Adding Private GCP Repo Breaks normal `pip` behaviour

When using Google Cloud Platform's Artifact Repository, you have to alter your `.pypirc` file for any uploads (`twine`) and your `pip.conf` for any downloads (`pip`).

For the downloads specifically, you have to add something like:

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://<YOUR-LOCATION>-python.pkg.dev/<YOUR-PROJECT>/<YOUR-REPO-NAME>/simple/
```

However, by doing this, now *anything* that will call `pip` will also check this extra repository, and when doing so, it will ask for a user name and password.  This means that anything, like calls behind the scenes that `poetry`, `pdm`, `pip`, or `pipx` do will all ask for this username and password.  Often these requests are being made as part of a non-interactive action, so that everything just stalls.

## Non-ideal, but working, solution:

I ran across [this "solution"](https://towardsdatascience.com/if-you-are-using-python-and-google-cloud-platform-this-will-simplify-life-for-you-part-2-bef56354fd4c), which does indeed work, but which the author himself says is not the *right* way to do things because it compromises security, bringing us back to the "infinitely live keys stored on a laptop" days.

(I'm sorry, that link is now behind Medium's paywall.  In short, the link said that you should use a JSON key and provide that key in your `pip.conf` and `.pypirc` files. You can create a JSON key following something like this [Google doc showing how to authenticate with a key file](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#keyring-user).)

## More secure solution??

But what is the right solution?  I want the following:

1. To be able to run things like `pip`, `pdm`, etc. on my local machine and not have them stall, waiting for a username and password that I cannot fill out.

   - This is both for things that are in fact in my private repository, but also things living in normal PYPI or wherever I look.
2. To keep the security in place, so that I am being recognized as "ok to do this" because I have authorized myself and my computer via `gcloud auth login` or something similar (`gcloud auth login` does nothing to assist with this repo issue, at least not with any flags I tried).
3. And still be able to perform `twine` actions (upload to registry) without problems.
4. I use newer solutions, specifically `pdm`, for package build. I need something that uses `pyproject.toml`, not `setup.py`, etc. If I perform something like `pdm install` (or `poetry install`), I need for credentials to be evaluated without human input.

Comment: Have checked these threads: [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72280347/18265570) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68998902/18265570)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked those threads.  I'm looking for something secure that does not rely upon keys / passwords.  I'd rather be able to use proper IAM credentials.  Ie, when I work locally, I type `gcloud auth login`, and there is no *stale* password required.  But those two threads both require keys/passwords that will _either_ become stale, or have to be rotated.  It's 2023 and I'm hoping for a 21st century auth solution...

Answer (score 2):

Reading the links and the comments to your question, you will want to follow [Google's Authenticating with keyring](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#keyring) guide.

This should allow you to once, locally authenticate by using `gcloud auth login` and have access to the registry, then if you log out lose access to it. It should also not prompt you for more input if you have your keyring unlocked.

I highly recommend reading their documentation as it's pretty straight forward, but for the sake of a complete answer (as of 2023/09) for any future searches I'll include the base steps below.

This should cover your base requirements except if by `I need for credentials to be evaluated without human input` you meant for CI/CD. Then you'll probably need to open another question.

---

##### 1. Install the keyring library and the google artifact registry library plugin

```
pip install keyring
pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
```

##### 2. Check that the GAuth backend was installed and detected by keyring

```
keyring --list-backends|grep GooglePythonAuth
# should output something like:
> keyrings.gauth.GooglePythonAuth (priority: x)
```

##### 3. Login via Google Cloud CLI

```
gcloud auth login
```

##### 4. Configure `twine` to know about the artifact registry

NB: `$PYTHON_REPO_ID`, `$LOCATION`, `$PROJECT_ID`, and `$REPOSITORY_ID` are all things you personally have to set/change.

- `$PYTHON_REPO_ID` is a human-readable ID for using with twine/poetry/pdm.
- `$LOCATION` is the regional or multi-regional location for the repository (in terms of Google Cloud).
- `$REPOSITORY_ID` is the ID of the Artifact Registry
- `$PROJECT_ID` is the project ID in GCP

```bash
#.pypirc
[disutils]
index-servers =
    $PYTHON_REPO_ID

[$PYTHON_REPO_ID]
repository = https://$LOCATION-python.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$REPOSITORY_ID
```

##### 5. Configure `pip` to know about the artifact registry

Same as the `repository =` value above. You can either write this globally to `/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf` (not recommended), to the user at `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf` (better, but not per project), per virtualenv at `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf`, or where ever you want by setting the `PIP_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable to point to a specific location.

```bash
#pip.conf
[global]
extra-index-url = https://$LOCATION-python.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$REPOSITORY_ID
```

---

At this point, you should be able to just `gcloud auth login` and access your artifact registry using python tooling that utilizes pip itself. Since it's set as an `extra-index-url` instead of a `index-url`, it'll supplement whatever is on PyPI with what's in your registry.

As for using twine, it's just adding the `-r` flag and specifying the `$PYTHON_REPO_ID` you used earlier.

For example:

`twine upload -r $PYTHON_REPO_ID dist/*`

Comment: Thanks!  However, as you note, you're using `gcloud auth login`.  This is not something that can be done when trying to create packages.  For instance, `poetry update` or `pdm update` will fail because it cannot make these arbitrary calls. (I don't use Poetry, not sure if it's `poetry update` in Poetry.)

I *am* able to build packages as part of the CI/CD since the service account has the proper rights, but then I cannot build the packages locally, since I cannot run `pdm update` locally.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson The entire point of this is that you unlock your keyring which contains the username and password and supplies it to pip instead of bothering you for the values. The keyring GAuth backend interfaces and gets the values from `gcloud auth login` and provides those to pip. Here's the citation: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#keyring-user

Comment: Yes, I understand, @plunker.  But, I want something that can assume a user.  In your case, you are either manually downloading or manually uploading.  When you use `pyproject.toml`, those things happen on your behalf.  (Again, with `pdm update`, for instance.)  As your link shows, I need a _key file_.  If I do this in CI/CD within Google's cloud, I don't need a key file; the account that I am _building with_ has permissions.  I don't want a key file that can get stale.  I want to run my local deploy with my personal Google account, which also has sufficient permissions. No key file.

Comment: Google's documentation is pretty bad as it tends to flow all together. In what I described there is no need for a keyfile if you utilize their keyring registry backend.  You authenticate via `gcloud auth login` and the credentials are stored in the keyring. A keyring is not a keyfile. https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-keyring/

Comment: Yes, I agree that it isn't very good. :(  Maybe we can take this as a side conversation, but first let me just ask:  have you used PDM or Poetry to build packages that have dependencies on other private packages?  If not, I think that might be the confusion.  You're thinking that I can _interact_ with the CLI, but I cannot.  I type `pdm build`, and it is PDM that is now interacting directly.

Comment: I have and I understand how it works.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I have created this room, which might be easier, if you still have time to assist:  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255340/gcp-private-repo-used-as-dependency-for-python-package